# How to print a number with dots thousands separators in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have this problem where I wanna put a dot after every 3 digits to notice the difference when you have thousands. At this moment I'm using commas and I wanna change it, but I didn't find a solution yet. I wanna do it here because i don't wanna send the dot's to the backend. I just need to change the regex but i don't know how.

Here is the code:

```
<InputNumber
    min={1}
    step={100}
    style={{ width: FORM_ITEM_WIDTH }}
    formatter={(value) => ` ${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')}
    parser={(value) => value.replace(/\$\s?|(,*)/g, '')}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use **numeral**.

Here is link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/numeral

http://numeraljs.com/

There are plenty of examples how to use it.
Here is how it works:

> ```
> var string = numeral(1000).format('0,0'); // '1,000'
> ```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. It doesn't work that fine with me because i don't want to send a dot to de backend that's why i wanna do it on the front end side. Isn't there a better regex or something?